# Is the identity the only matrix unchanged by unitary tranformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Say we have a matrix $M$ and we know that $M = UMU^\dagger$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $^\dagger$ indicates the conjugate transpose. It is clear that $M = k I $ is a solution, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $k$ is some scalar.

My question is whether this is the only possible solution for $M$? If so, is there a proof for this? If not, can it be made true by adding extra restrictions (eg. if we make the restriction that $M$ is symmetric or that $U$ is orthogonal rather than unitary).

Comment: It is also clear that $M = U$ and $M = U^\dagger$ are solutions.  Is $U$ fixed, or are we saying that $M  = UMU^\dagger$ for all unitary matrices $U$?

Comment: Since $U U^{\dagger} = I$, so $M = U$ or $M = U^{\dagger}$ are solutions as well

Comment: [This is strongly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118030/8157)

Comment: Oh, of course I have assumed that you mean $U^\dagger M U= M$ **for all unitary** $U$. Otherwise, the problem is very much underdetermined, there are many matrices, other than $kI$, satisfying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can rewrite your equation as
$$
M = UMU^\dagger \implies MU = UM.
$$

By the spectral theorem for normal matrices, there exists a unitary matrix $V$ such that $U = VDV^\dagger$, where $D$ is diagonal and unitary.  $M$ will necessarily commute with $U$ if $M$ has the form $M = VD_MV^\dagger$, where $D_M$ is any diagonal matrix.

If the eigenvalues of $U$ are distinct, then these are the only matrices $M$ that satisfy $MU = UM$.